# null value post on controller from html helper dropdown in mvc5

Tags: c#

I use the mvc 5 for learning purpose.
When I send the data on controller from drop down list then object has null value in controller.

## Model Code:

```
    namespace Dropdownlist.Models
    {
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;

       public partial class Country
       {
           public int ID { get; set; }
           public string CountryName { get; set; }
       }
    }
```

## Controller Code:

```
    namespace Dropdownlist.Controllers
    {
        public class HOMEController : Controller
        {
            DropDownEntities db = new DropDownEntities();
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(Country cn)
            {
                db.Countries.Add(cn);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View(cn);
            }
       }
   }
```

## View Code:

```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   }

   <h2>Index</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
   {
       <div>
           @Html.DropDownList("ddlcountry", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem{ Text = "India", Value = "India"},
               new SelectListItem{ Text = "UK", Value = "UK"},
               new SelectListItem{ Text = "USA", Value = "USA"}
           }, "Select a Country")
       </div>
       <div>
           <input type="submit" value="Save" />
       </div>
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need ID to be set?

Comment: Why do you think it should send you the data to the controller

Answer (score 1):

If you want both `ID` and `CountryName` value to be posted back, then you will need to have the control name match the property of your model, and your view should be strongly typed so that you can use `Html.DropDownListFor()` helper, right now you can do it like:

```
 @model Dropdownlist.Models.Country
 @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   }

   <h2>Index</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
   {
       <div>
           @Html.DropDownList("ID", new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "India", Value = 1},
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "UK", Value = 2},
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "USA", Value = 2}
       }, "Select a Country",new { id="ddlCountry"})

       @Html.Hidden("CountryName")
       </div>
       <div>
           <input type="submit" value="Save" />
       </div>
   }
```

and countryName you would need to set it in a hidden field and set it's value when dropdown index is changed like:

```
@section Scripts
{

 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#ddlCountry").on("change", function () {

             $("#CountryName").val($(this).val());

         });

     });
    </script>   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `CountryName` property change your view to this:

```
....
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.CountryName, new List<SelectListItem>
....
```

Comment: You can't set both of the property at the same time, I see the `Value` is a string type, so I guess it would be `CountryName`.

Comment: The the action should accept a string not a country object.

Comment: @GlennPacker It's not important, It will set automatically and the other one would be null.

Comment: it is important if you ever want to use that Id for anything. Countries will end up with different Id's. This means you could never repopulate the drop down list. The model is fundamentally in error.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this person uses Value as its Text!

Answer (score 0):

you have several issues here. The dropdown has a name of "ddlcountry" but the action is expecting a Country object which does not have a property of ddlcountry. ddlcountry is a string india/uk/usa. The form should be returning an Id which the cross references another table. The form as it stands does not make any sense as there is only one piece of data.

Answer (score 0):

Load you drop down data from controller

```
ViewBag.DropDown = db.YourModel.ToList();
```

and then in your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDown, "Select ...")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here but i think your after something like this:

an enum for your select list items:

```
    public enum Countries
    {
        India = 1,
        UK = 2,
        USA = 3
    }
```

then for the controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Country = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries)).Cast<Countries>().ToList().Select(r => new SelectListItem { Text = r.ToString(), Value = ((int)r).ToString() });

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Countries country)
    {
        var saveit = country;
        // whatever you wish to do with the result;
        return Content(saveit.ToString());
    }
```

The View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Country")
    <button type="submit" >Save</button>
}
```